# R or ArcGis: average per polygon of the shortest distance to a river from each point in that polygon

Tags: arcgis-10.1, polygon, r, distance, rivers

All the shapefiles necessary can be found [here](http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/wise-large-rivers-and-large-lakes). These are shapefiles of lakes, and rivers. Downloading one shapefile as an example should be enough to get me on the right track.

The nuts file can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0By9u5m3kxn9yfjZtdFZLcW82SWpzT1VwZXE1a3FtRGtSdEl1c1NvY205TGpack9xSFc2T2s&usp=sharing).

What I want is to **calculate the distance from each possible point in one nuts3-polygon to the nearest river**. If all the distances are calculated from each point, I want to determine **per nuts3-polygon what the average, minimum and maximum distance is to the nearest river, together with the standard deviation (if possible).**

My paint skills are probably not the best ever, but the idea is something like this picture below (for each of the dots). Then I would calculate the average of all the brown lines that originates from a point in the polygon.

I can work a bit with R and ArcGis. Online I do not find a solution that matches what I am looking for.

[image]

Comment: Given there's an infinite number of points in a polygon I think the way to do it is to simulate a large number of points in the polygon with uniform density and average the distance to the nearest line. Have you used the `rgeos` package? That will compute point-line distances.

Comment: This is most basic task using euclidian distance in and zonal statistics in arcgis

Comment: Hey @FelixIP. Thanks for the hint. I have only access to ArcGis on Thursday but I will test it and keep you up to date. However, I already tried earlier in ArcGis and remember that I didn't get it to work. So if you know the specific steps that would help a lot. Otherwise, I'll let you know on Thursday!

Comment: @Spacedman Thank you as well for your fast reaction and hint. I follow the logic in your comment. However, I have no experience with both suggestions. However, since I like working with R, I will try to make it work. If you could give me a hint on how to make the points in the polygon, you would help me again a lot!

Comment: I think you should focus your question on where you are stuck using ArcGIS for Desktop. You can always research/ask about R separately.

Comment: Thanks! I will give more details when I am back at university. Only there I can access ArcGis! I will let you know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created distances rasters to all 3 types of water bodies (cell size = 1000m*1000m) and used cell statistics (min) to find nearest distance. After that I ran zonal statistics as table and joined results back to polygons.

This is how max distance looks like:

[image]

What you call nuts is a set overlapping polygons, make sure to remove all with status < 3.

Comment: Yes indeed, there are 4 levels of nuts. Nuts0, nuts1, nuts2 and nuts3. However, your steps go too fast for me. Could you provide a little bit more details? Thank you very much!

Comment: There are 4 steps in my answer. How about following them and ask separate questions as you go. Even better use arcgis help system

Comment: Hey @FelixIP , I managed to do the last steps for one shapefile at the time. However, I do not understand how to make a distance raster for all the three shapefiles at once. 

Could you please provide more details here? Right now I can calculate the distance to for instance large rivers. But I cannot calculate the distance to the first river (whether it is large or small). I guess to be able to do this I need to build these distance rasters but I can't make it work.

Comment: You need 3 distance raster. After that run cell statistics (min) using all 3 of them